# Is it possible to remove the header part of a Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I would like to know if it's possible to remove the header part of a jqgrid (part with the title of the grid and the expand/collapse button).
Not the column header but the whole Grid header.

Thanks for your answers.

Bertrand

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want a header then just don't define the `caption` parameter of the jqGrid.

Comment: Sometimes things are too simple.

Thank you very much

Comment: but suppose he/she want title but don't like show/hide button then?

Comment: @imdadhusen: There are `hidegrid` jqGrid option.