# how to hide jqgrid header while the grid content is loading?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

For reasons, I need to hide the default header that is generated by jqgrid and set my own header for it. For a demo I am trying something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/92da8xhq/10/).

```
        loadComplete:function(){
        //$(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").css("display","none");
        $(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv").css("display","none");
        if (!$(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").next().hasClass("newheader"))
        {
            $("<div class='newheader'><div class='col-md-6''> FirstText </div><div class='col-md-6'> SecondText </div></div>").insertAfter(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar");           
        }

    },
```

But my implementation has 13 columns and 50 rows also it is "grouping" grid.

At present it takes around 4 seconds to populate the grid. During this loading time the default header is showing up. But I wish to hide it while the content is loading. How can I do it?

In one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474974/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-header-part-of-a-jqgrid), I came to know that in order to hide the header we have to omit caption. But I need the caption but not the header. Help me on this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you want to change the grid layout (all outer dives and headers) only and not the grid body. The grid layout will be created *immediately* after you create jqGrid. On the other side `loadComplete` will be called after **the data** will be loaded. All your current code inside of `loadComplete` has no relation to the data. Thus you can move the code from outside of jqGrid. Additionally you can just remove `caption` parameter if you don't want to display the header. After that you can remove unneeded line `$(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar").css("display","none");`. The code will be

```
// create the grid
$("#grid1").jqGrid({
    ...
});
$(".ui-jqgrid-hdiv").css("display","none");
$("<div class='newheader'><div class='col-md-6''>FirstText</div><div class='col-md-6'>SecondText</div></div>").insertAfter(".ui-jqgrid-titlebar");
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/92da8xhq/11/. I added `$("#grid1").jqGrid("GridUnload");` before creating the grid because your current code can call `showgrid` function more as once.

Comment: Oleg, Yes you are correct. The layout is what I wanted to change. And your answer was really helpful. Problem is solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use gridComplete instead of loadComplete , but this is true if you use Guriddo jqGrid, or your code can be enclosed in setTimeout function, before to show your own header

Comment: Thank you Tony Tomov. But I am sorry, now I use the free-jqgrid downloaded from its  github page. Coming to the problem, how else can I accomplish this?

Comment: You can try what I suggest you, but in any case the second approach using setTimeout will help

Comment: Tony Tomov, Yeah I was trying the setTimeout function as well. But Oleg's answer was more helpful. So I accepted that answer. Thank you so much for your useful response.